# Cannot change pins for images in a map

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mapkit, swift2, cllocationmanager

I have a map where I mark points based on Parse data. This works correctly. When I try to change the red pins of the map with a custom image, it seems that everything is OK but when I run the app in the simulator, the red pins are there and my image doesn't appear. I have tried some similar versions of the code I have with the same result. I tried to print the annotationView in the console and seems that have the image saved the line before the return. Where is the error? What I have to do to show the custom image correctly? Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var MapViewLocationManager:CLLocationManager! = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLoc: PFGeoPoint! = PFGeoPoint()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)
        annotationQuery.whereKey("restaurant", equalTo: true)
        annotationQuery.whereKey("restaurantPosition", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinMiles: 6000)
        annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (posts, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successful query for annotations")
                let myPosts = posts as [PFObject]!

                for post in myPosts {
                    let point = post["restaurantPosition"] as! PFGeoPoint
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)

                    self.mapViewN(self.mapView, viewForAnnotation: annotation).annotation = annotation
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func mapViewN(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView {

        let identifier = "pin"

    // Reuse the annotation if possible
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "map_marker_2")

        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        print(annotationView?.image)
        return annotationView!
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method map view:viewForAnnotation: is misnamed. You have

```
func mapViewN(mapView: MKMapView, 
  viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView
```

That N in the name does not belong there, so your delegate method will never be called. 
(The method name for a delegate method must be exactly correct or the method doesn't get called. For a required delegate method you may even crash.)

It should be:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, 
  viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapViewN:viewForAnnotation` delegate is called?

Maybe you should rename `mapViewN` to `mapView`.

```
func mapViewN(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView {
```

->

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
```

Comment: It absolutely SHOULD be `mapView`, not `mapViewN`. If the delegate method name is wrong it won't be called.